# I couldn't be able to reach my .net core back end on windows server iis from my computer

Tags: angular, windows, iis, .net-core, server

I've created an app with angular for FE and .net core for BE. I've published it and located on windows server iis. The app works fine inside server. I can login and use the app. But when i tried to reach the app from my computer I got error. I can not login.  When I check the error it says **"POST http://111.222.3.444:555(REMOVED)/api/v1/Authenticate/post net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"** and another issue is the app trying to reach **"http://111.222.3.444:555(REMOVED)/api/v1/User/get/NaN"**. But in my application there is no path like **"..../api/v1/User/get/NaN"**. it must try to reach **".../api/v1/User/get"**. I'm not sending a value which might correspond to "NaN" part.

Sum up,

My app works fine when i use it on server, but when i try to use it on my computer it returns error.

BTW i set timeout value to connectionString to solve **"CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"** error like
**"Server=111.222.3.444;Database=aaa;User ID = user_id; Password = pass;connect timeout=5000;"**, it also didn't work.

Any help or pointing to the right direction is really appreciated. Thank you!

EDİT 1 // service for Authentication api

```
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticateService {

  user: User;
  private apiURL = environment.apiUrl + '/Authenticate';
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient, private router: Router, private cookieService: CookieService) { }

  public  loginPost(): Observable<Auth> {
    return this.httpclient.post<Auth>(this.apiURL + "/post", this.user);
  }
}
```

EDİT 2 //service for user api

```
public GetUsers(): Observable<User[]> {

    return this.httpclient.get<User[]>(this.apiURL + '/get', { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

Comment: you have to share the code of service from where you initiate the request to API, problem is over there and not in your server, also trying reaching to server from your machine that should be accessible

Comment: it would be great if edit your question and add code there

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I leave the solution to my problem here so it can help people who are new to iis like me. I added the Backend and FrontEnd projects as two separate websites, and I assigned separate ports to both of them. Therefore, when the frontend project runs properly on the default iis port (: 80), the port of the backend project is not allowed in the windows firewall, it rejects external requests. When I allowed the port of the Backend project in the firewall, the problem was resolved.

Comment: That's only a partial solution, as opening too many ports on your firewall is not a good idea and you might have to open more if you get other services developed in the future. Learn ARR and reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing and then you can see how easy it is to expose everything at port 80.